# How to use REGEX to capitalise the first letter of the first word in a sentence?

Tags: regex

I would like to use regular expressions (REGEX) to capitalise the first letter of the first word in a sentence. Other words shuld be in lowercase:

My sentence:
Ask A Question

Result:
**A**sk **a** **q**uestion

Comment: What have you tried so far? How far did you get?

Comment: What context is this in? Is it a document, website, spreadsheet, etc.?

Comment: What operating system or program would you use for this?

Comment: @raphael75 I'll be use it for finding and replacing value of custom HTML attribute (i use WebStorm).

So I have following attribute: data-test="Ask A Question".

WebStorm should replace it to data-test="Ask a question".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what regex flavour is used within WebStorm, but here is a way to go with PCRE regex flavour:

- Find: `(.)(.+)`
- Replace: `\U$1\L$2`